# Cordova not able to find JAVA

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I am trying to create android application from angular app using cordova. But every time I am getting error

> **Cannot read property 'version' of null**
> [image]

I have followed the COrdova documentation and also checked the java version I am using is jdk1.8. I have added Java, Gradle, Android all in path variables. See the screenshot for reference. But still the issue persist.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Common problem for me, but i prefer to create release builds using Android studio. Thats why i have installed Android studio - usually that fixes those issues =) But thats not a solution ofc

Comment: @Cheese Actually I am not an Android developer and the project for which I am using Cordova as a workaround for the above fact  is not that of worth to hire Android developer.

Comment: me too, but installing the Android Studio usually fixes the ENV settings issues, but that is just a workaround that i use sometimes

Comment: @Cheese I have tried that option also and have downloaded sdk  till android 9 but still no luck.